# Prevent the closing of select dropdown on selecting input box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Im using antd select component and using the dropdownRender option to make a customized dropdown.
I have an autocomplete component in the dropdown but on click of the input box the select component close. How do I prevent the closing event. My code is in the link https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-chatelet-ps907?file=/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Select, Icon, Divider, AutoComplete, Input } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;
const dataSource = ["Burns Bay Road", "Downing Street", "Wall Street"];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: ["jack", "lucy"]
  };
  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <Select
        style={{ width: 240 }}
        placeholder="custom dropdown render"
        dropdownRender={menu => (
          <div>
            {menu}
            <Divider style={{ margin: "4px 0" }} />
            <div
              style={{ padding: "4px 8px", cursor: "pointer" }}
              onMouseDown={e => e.preventDefault()}
            >
              Locations
              <AutoComplete
                style={{ width: 200 }}
                dataSource={dataSource}
                placeholder="try to type `b`"
                filterOption={(inputValue, option) =>
                  option.props.children
                    .toUpperCase()
                    .indexOf(inputValue.toUpperCase()) !== -1
                }
              >
                <Input
                  suffix={
                    <Icon type="search" className="certain-category-icon" />
                  }
                />
              </AutoComplete>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      >
        {items.map(item => (
          <Option key={item}>{item}</Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using old version of antd and therefore you are facing the issue of select getting closed.

Upgrade to 4.x version, it should work. Also [Icons](https://ant.design/components/icon/) have changed in new releases so use latest components.

[See here working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-select-should-not-close-fix-q0wsz?file=/index.js) - the select is not closing upon clicking & typing in the input